# What's the simplest way in Ruby to concurrently send a keypress to the terminal?

Tags: ruby, input, terminal, keypress, tty

I have a program that, via a library, asks for input.

The library has an autofill functionality, triggered via Tab key, but it doesn't provide any way to trigger it programmatically.

I'm therefore trying a simple way to programmatically send the Tab keypress to the terminal.

Since the program runs on Linux, a workaround is to spin a thread running xdotool:

```rb
require "highline"
Thread.new { sleep 0.1; system("xdotool key Tab BackSpace" }
HighLine.new.ask("") { |q| q.completion = ["preset text"]; q.readline = true }
```

Is there a way to perform this via Ruby stdlib (or any gem), rather than manually invoking `xdotool`?

The target is Linux, so a Linux-only approach is acceptable - primarily, I'd like for it not to be tied to a specific Linux program (xdotool may not be installed, for example).

Comment: Have you tried using [`putc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-putc) instead of xdotool?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks! Where should I send it to?

Comment: It sends to stdout, it might work, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @Marcus please share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Chandan sure, done.